# Object design decision on complicated object C# - HL7 message

Tags: c#, object, data-modeling, hl7-v2

I'm attempting to create an object of an HL7 message by parsing a raw text string.

The object model is a follows.
[image]

The object I want to create would be a representation of this, allowing calling methods to access information based on indexes. If information from the 2nd sub-subfield in the 3rd subfield of the 5th field of the segment named "PID" for the message you'd do it like this:

```
HL7Message h = HL7Message(messageRawText);

Console.Writeline(h.GetInfo("PID",5,3,2)+" is sub-subfield I'm looking for")
```

I'd also like to access at higher levels e.g.

```
Console.Writeline(h.GetInfo("PID",5)+" is field I'm looking for")
```

Approaches I've considered are

> 1. creating an object that has fields that are lists of strings
> 2. creating an object that has fields that other user defined objects of Segments, Fields, Subfields...

What would be the best approach? I imagine the scenario must exist somewhere, but can't find a neat fit for my solution.

Comment: Wouldn't this be best served with strongly typed properties, like `h.Segments["PID"].Fields[5].Subfields[3].SubSubFields[2]`?

Comment: Go with the second option.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  -what syntax do I use for this? Is there a tutorial for it?