# C# Object modelling 1:n:m... realtionships

Tags: c#, object, data-modeling

How do I create an object that has properties with multiple related properties that have multiple related properties and so on?

I'm creating a C# class that will describe toe disease on a various colonies of tigers.

One colony has many tigers. 1 tiger has 4 paws. 1 paw has 5 toes. Each toes is "infected" or "not infected".

How can I construct an object that will retrieve diseased status for the colony 4's tiger named Eddy's front-right paw's second toe? e.g.

```
 Tiger t = new Tiger;

 string toeStatus = t.colony(4).tiger("Eddy").paw("front-right").toe(2)
```

I've only every had to create objects that have properties unto themselves, not have properties that relate to properties that relate to properties.

I'd also like to re-use this object to get the names of all the names of all the tigers for a given colony...

```
string allTigersNames = t.colony(4).tiger(*)
//Eddy, Glennis, Barry, Toby, Punter
```

I've asked in an analogous [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552056/object-design-decision-on-complicated-object-c-sharp-hl7-message?noredirect=1#comment101569284_57552056) and have been given a response that I don't understand at my present experience level. Particularly the approach to use strongly typed properties.

Comment: You are best to start with strongly typed models. then it would be as simple as just using *linq* to query it... Maybe at this stage you need to paste the code for `Tiger` (which... mind you, doesn't conceptually make sense). how can a *tiger* have *subtigers*?

Comment: Thanks my problem is I don't understand what's meant by "strongly typed models". My searches return references to "strongly typed views" and articles on how C# is a strongly typed language.

Comment: We need to see the code of `Tiger` to know where you are at

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Colony
{
    public int ColonyId {get; set;}
    public string ColonyName {get; set;}
    public List<Tiger> Tigers {get; set;}
}

public class Tiger
{
    public int TigerId {get; set;}
    public string TigerName {get; set;}
    public Colony Colony {get; set;}
    public List<Paw> Paws {get; set;}
}

public class Paw
{
    public int PawId {get; set;}
    public string PawDescription {get; set;}
    public Tiger Tiger {get; set;}
    public List<Toe> Toes {get; set;}
}

public class Toe
{
    public int ToeId {get; set;}
    public Paw Paw {get; set;}
    public int ToeFinger {get; set;}
}
```

this would be my hierarchy if you will ask me

```
Colony > Multiple Tigers
Tiger > Multiple Paws
Paw > Multiple Toes
```

then adding would look like these

```
var primaryColony = new Colony
{
    ColonyId = 1,
    ColonyName = "First Colony",
    Tigers = new List<Tigers>();
};

var colonies = new List<Colonies>();


//adding primary colony
colonies.Add(primaryColony);

//adding tiger to primary colony via name or you could use ColonyId == 1
colonies.First(c => c.ColonyName == "First Colony")
.Tigers.Add(new Tiger
{
    TigerId = 1,
    TigerName = "Eddy",
    Paws = new List<Paw>();,
    Colony = primaryColony
});

//adding paws to tiger named eddy in colony named primary colony
colonies.First(e => e.ColonyName == "First Colony")
.Tigers.First(r => r.TigerName == "Eddy")
.Paws.Add(new Paw
{
    PawId = 1,
    PawDescription = "right-front",
    Toes = new List<Toes>();,
    Tiger = colonies.First(e => e.ColonyName == "First Colony")
.Tigers.First(r => r.TigerName == "Eddy")
});

//adding toes to right front paw of tiger named eddy in colony named first colony
colonies.First(e => e.ColonyName == "First Colony")
.Tigers.First(r => r.TigerName == "Eddy")
.Paws.First(q => q.PawDescription == "right-front")
.First().Toes.Add(new Toe
{
    ToeId = 1,
    ToeFinger = 1,
    Paw = colonies.First(e => e.ColonyName == "First Colony")
.Tigers.First(r => r.TigerName == "Eddy")
.Paws.First(q => q.PawDescription == "right-front")
});
```

or if you have a filter, like you want paws to add to TigerName = Eddy

```
var tigerEddy = colonies.Select(y => new Tiger
{
    TigerId = y.Tigers.FirstOrDefault?.(c => c.TigerName == "Eddy").Select(e => e.TigerId),
    TigerName = y.Tigers.FirstOrDefault?.(c => c.TigerName == "Eddy").Select(e => e.TigerName),
    Colony = y.Tigers.FirstOrDefault?.(c => c.TigerName == "Eddy").Select(e => e.Colony)
    Paws = y.Tigers.FirstOrDefault?.(c => c.TigerName == "Eddy").Select(e => e.Paws)
}.Any(x => x.Tigers.Containes("Eddy").FirstOrDefault();

tigerEddy.Paws.Add(new Paws.....);
```

then pass it back to colonies with `TigerId` as the reference